# Is it ever okay to violate first normal form?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, database-normalization

I have an Access database that will be required to present data with several one-to-many relationships on one row (e.g., it would list items as "a, b, e, f", and I would have multiple columns like that). I know it's a bad idea to store data that way as well, but considering that I'm allowing the user to filter on several of these columns, I can't think of a better way of dealing with the data than violating first normal form.

As an example: say that I have several journal articles, each of which may report on multiple animals and multiple vegetables. The user can filter on the source name, or they can filter on one or more animals and one or more vegetables. The output should look like

```
Source name....animals...............vegetables
Source 1.......dogs, cats, birds.....carrots, tomatoes
Source 2.......leopards, birds.......tomatoes, zucchini, apples
Source 3.......cats, goldfish........carrots, cucumbers
```

Typically you would have a separate table with Source name + animal:

```
Source name......animal
Source 1.........dog
Source 1.........cats
Source 1.........birds
Source 2.........leopards
```

etc

and a similar table for vegetables. But considering how the data needs to be presented to the user (a comma-separated list), and how the user filters the data (he may filter to only see sources that include dogs and cats, and sources with carrots and tomatoes), I think it makes sense to store the data as comma separated lists for animals and vegetables. With a comma-separated list, when the user selects multiple vegetables and multiple animals, I can say

```
WHERE (Vegetables like "*carrots*" and Vegetables like "*tomatoes*") AND (Animals like *dogs*" and Animals like "*cats*")
```

I can't think of an efficient way to do this same kind of query in Access without using a lot of VBA and multiple queries.

Comment: There is usually at least one very good reason to break any rule.  I feel that Access is sometimes very hard to work with and sometimes it is just so much easier initially and when considering the long term to not have a completely relational database schema.  It really depends, though.  I once had to de-normalize an Access DB because some of the reporting was becoming very complex due to a 3NF design.  However, I think this can be done without any VBA and with a normalized design.

Comment: Sure hope you're not going to have to track prairie dogs in your database.

Answer (score 4):

You can always construct a scenario in which violating any rule makes sense, so the answer to the question in your title is Yes.

This is not one of those scenarios, however.  The searching and presentation issues you raise are common to most one-to-many relationships (or, at least, to *many* one-to-many relationships) and if this were a reason to violate first normal form then you wouldn't see a lot of normalized databases.

Construct the database correctly and you won't have to worry about commas, search terms embedded in each other, and slow searches due to the lack of indexes.  Write a reusable piece of code to perform the comma-separate roll-ups for you so you don't keep reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am suggesting that the be *stored* in correct, normalized format and converted for display into whatever format is appropriate, including comma-delimited format.  The display issue can be addressed by a piece of common code that can be reused where ever that functionality is required (I've done that both in Access VBA and in other client languages using JET as the engine).

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I think you're answer would be more useful if you'd include those details in it. I suppose you would recommend not editing in the comma delimmetted field, etc. I think it would also be good if you'd say a little how the query might look. Would you use subqueries in the Where clause or would you use several joins to the same table with appropriate Where clause/conditions? Or some other, better idea yet?

Comment: Hey HK1, in case this might help you out, I took everyone's advice and normalized correctly (as my instinct told me to). It really didn't end up being much of a hassle to concatenate rows later on. I normalized all my data appropriately and then modified Allen Browne's function ConcatRelated (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to group the data I needed for display.

Answer (score 0):

i would still normalize this properly - and then worry about the presentation.

in Oracle - this would be done with a user defined aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not contruct a Join Table so you can sustain the 1:1 in relationship to field referential integrity.  Otherwise you will have to parse out the 1:many field value to then get a referential association so everything works magically (hehehe ;))

When i find myself in need to violate the 1st normal form, the answer 9:10 is to create a Join Table and construct some methodology to produce the desired effect.

### Edited: 2012-10-09 9:06AM

- This design was in response to an unknown amount of information to be displayed in an unknown amount of column/fields.  Although mine is oriented towards numerical values, you could simply develop a vba method to concatenate the information fields to produce a singular field of data.

#### Table1

```
gid (Number) <- Table2.id
cid (Number) <- Table3.id
price (Number)
```

- gid MANY <- ONE Table2.id
- cid MANY <- ONE Table3.id

#### crt_CategoryPG

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Table1.price) AS SumOfprice
SELECT View1.tid, Table1.cid, View1.category
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (View1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON View1.cid = Table1.cid) ON Table2.gid = Table1.gid
WHERE (((Table2.active)=True) AND ((View1.active)=True))
GROUP BY View1.tid, Table1.cid, View1.category, Table2.active, View1.active
ORDER BY View1.tid, Table1.cid
PIVOT [Table2].[gid] & " - " & [Table2].[nm];
```

#### Refresh the CT Table

```
Public Function RefreshCategoryPricing(Optional sql As String = "")
    If HasValue(lstType) Then
Application.Echo False      'Turn off Screen Updating

        Dim cttbl As String: cttbl = CreateCTTable("crt_CategoryPG") 'Create Table to store the Cross-Tab information
        If IsNullOrEmpty(sql) Then
            sql = SQLSelect(cttbl)
        End If

        Dim flds As DAO.Recordset: Set flds = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
        Dim fldwd As String, fldhd As String      'Store the Field Width pattern and Field Header Row
        fldhd = "-1;-1;Category"
        fldwd = "0"";0"";2.5"""   'Handles `tid`, `cid`, and `category` columns in the ListBox
        'Assign the number of columns based on the number of fields in CTtable
        lstCategoryPG.ColumnCount = flds.Fields.Count

        Dim fld As Long
        For fld = 3 To (flds.Fields.Count - 1)
            fldwd = fldwd & ";.75"""
            fldhd = fldhd & ";" & flds.Fields(fld).Name
        Next

        GC flds

        lstCategoryPG.ColumnHeads = True
        lstCategoryPG.ColumnWidths = fldwd

        sql = SQLSelect(cttbl, , ("tid = " & lstType.Value))

        lstCategoryPG.Enabled = True
        RefreshControl CurrentDb, lstCategoryPG, sql, , False
        lstCategoryPG.AddItem fldhd, 0

Application.Echo True       'Turn on Screen Updating
    End If
End Function
```

#### Create Cross-Tab Table

```
'@ct - String value, Source Cross-Tab to base Table design off of
Public Function CreateCTTable(ct As String) As String
    Dim tbl As String: tbl = "tbl_" & ct
    Dim sql As String

    If TableExists(tbl) Then
    'Table exists and needs to be dropped
        sql = SQLDrop(tbl)
        CurrentDb.Execute sql
    End If

    'Create Table
    sql = SQLSelect(ct, "* INTO " & tbl)
    CurrentDb.Execute sql

    CreateCTTable = tbl
End Function
```

Comment: Using your method, how would you display this data in a single row, like a Query or Datasheet for for example, without listing each row in the "source table" once for each row in the "join table"?

Comment: Well depending on what their situation is you could construct a table to contains the fields necessary for the information and create table ad-hoc once you get the normalization complete.  Ive done it for a current client, its a PITA but doable and if done correctly can allow you to build an ad-hoc Cross-Tab table that is updateable to the source tables.

Comment: I think I know what you mean but I have never heard of an "ad-hoc cross-tab table" before.

Comment: @HK1 well i built one due to the nature of the project.  Drop it before i build the table contents and then rebuild the Table once i get the Cross-Tab field names.  Its clunky, considering VBA, but i did this alot in MS-SQL when i was building a Data-Warehouse for reporting into a SharePoint derivative product.  Most due to the fact that Cross-Tabs are not unformattable (easily), so i have to load all the referencial integrity values into non-visible fields.

Comment: Ill post the method i used in one of my projects.  Its a mix between VBA and DB-Queries, mostly run in VBA.

Comment: @HK1, in case you don't see my response above, this may be different than GoldBishop's response (I'm looking forward to seeing that as well). I took everyone's advice and normalized correctly (as my instinct told me to). It really didn't end up being much of a hassle to concatenate rows later on. I normalized all my data appropriately and then modified Allen Browne's function ConcatRelated (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) to group the data I needed for display.

Comment: @HK1 ok posted the design....have a bunch of helper methods performing some SQL Statement structuring but should get the point acrossed.

Comment: @user1102199 You will need to customize the Cross-Tab table to your need but basically should get you what you want, based on the design structure.