# SQL query to copy table with specified columns

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I've a table that 'll populate columns dynamically like col1,col2,col3... at runtime and i'm copying this table into another table having columns col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 more than this i.e. maximum number of columns it support. But currently when ever i copied dynamic generated table into current table having max columns it giving me error like

**Dynamic table columns:**
DateInterval, DataType, Seqno, Channel1_data, Channel1_status, Channel2_data, Channel2_status

**Table columns used for copying dynamic table:**
DateInterval, DataType, Seqno, Channel1_data, Channel1_status, Channel2_data, Channel2_status, Channel3_data, Channel3_status, Channel4_data, Channel4_status

**Query:**

```
    SELECT        DateInterval, DataType, Seqno, Channel1_data, Channel1_status, Channel2_data, Channel2_status, Channel3_data, Channel3_status, Channel4_data, Channel4_status
FROM          @TableName
```

'No value given for one or more required parameters'

Tell me how can i overcome this problem.

Thanks,
@nag

Comment: Perhaps, if you show the query text used, we can guess what is wrong.

Comment: can you show us the sql query. Most likely the problem lies in there. It mostly has to do with the '' or "" .. so if you show us what you have, we can solve it.

Comment: Do you allow null for the column values you aren't supplying? If you don't, then the database wont be able to know what value it's supposed to use if you don't supply a value for col4, for example.

Comment: @dash Yes 've to give null for not supplying columns

Comment: What value are you supplying for the parameter `@TableName`?

Comment: @dash Dynamic table name

Comment: How are you supplying it? It sounds like your query has the parameter defined but no value is being supplied for it (`No value given for one or more required parameters`)

Comment: It's having only one parameter table name but 'm passing it already, i think it showing that message becasue of extra columns having in it which we're not supplying it.

Comment: As long as your INSERT statement is of the form `INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col5) VALUES (1, 2, 5)` then the other rows in the table should be populated based on their default values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18099/discussion-between-nag-and-dash)

Comment: Chat is blocked where I work :-( The only thing I can suggest is looking to see if you have DEFAULT values specified for the columns so that if you don't supply the value, it will be populated with the default - see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp for SQL Server and http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-default-values-for-fields-or-controls-HA010096451.aspx for Access

Comment: Oh can you please tell me if you know how to set default values to the columns?

Comment: I'm copying dynamic table which is having two channels of channel1 and channel2 with table having 4 channels 1,2,3 and 4, so 3 and 4 channels having no data so i think that's why it giving that type of error. Tell me my assumption is correct or not?

Comment: @nag - the two links should tell you how to set the defaults for the columns.

Comment: @dash Well 'm looking into it, and Thank you so much for your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Nag review this posting: [Is it ever okay to violate the first normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679652/is-it-ever-okay-to-violate-first-normal-form/12679963#12679963)

In this posting you will find a way i solved a problem where i needed a variable number of fields, that would grow and shring over time, in a table.  It has minimal internal storage while still allowing for enough growth room for my need if the criteria was met.